# rosdep install trying to install from nonexistent brew repository

Tags: homebrew, ros

Why is rosdep trying to get me to install from a brew repo that doesn't exist? If I fetch these packages and install them manually, where do I need to put binaries?

```
$ rosdep install rgbdslam
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/message_runtime" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/perception_pcl" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/octomap" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/std_msgs" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/ros_comm" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/image_common" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/cmake_modules" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/pcl_conversions" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/catkin" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/vision_opencv" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/common_msgs" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/message_generation" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/libg2o" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
Error: No available formula with the name "ros/indigo/geometry" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/indigo
executing command [brew install ros/indigo/message_runtime]
==> Tapping ros/indigo
Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/ros/homebrew-indigo'...
Username for 'https://github.com': rollins.jackson@gmail.com
Password for 'https://rollins.jackson@gmail.com@github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/ros/homebrew-indigo/' not found
Error: Failure while executing: git clone https://github.com/ros/homebrew-indigo /usr/local/Library/Taps/ros/homebrew-indigo --depth=1
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  homebrew: command [brew install ros/indigo/message_runtime] failed
```